# Erro trying to run sudo npm i -g meta in ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu, npm

I am trying to run this comand in ubuntu

```
sudo npm i -g meta
```

But I am getting this error

```
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! An unknown git error occurred
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects clone ssh://git@github.com/mateodelnorte/commander.js.git /root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-2f61649e --recurse-submodules --depth=1
npm ERR! fatal: could not create leading directories of '/root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-2f61649e': Permission denied

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-05-09T14_04_24_178Z-debug-0.log
```

I tested the conection to git and it shows: "Hi username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access."

I do not know the root cause.
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Why do you use `sudo`? Do any of the dirs above not exist or exist with wrong permissions?

Comment: I am running in ubuntu, virutal machine in linux

Comment: "*I tested the conection to git…*" Tested without `sudo`, right? Re-test with `sudo` and you'll see the problem.